# WiFi Direct Demo

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct

I don't have a lot of knowledge on Java and new to Android development, but I need to use it for a project I am currently working on.
I have changed the WiFi Direct Demo code provided from android studio to send strings... 
the problem I have now is that I want to remove the section where the user gets asked to choose an image... and show the result in a Text View Box.

The following is the code from the "modified" WiFi Direct Demo

Device Detail Fragment Class:

```
 public class DeviceDetailFragment extends Fragment implements                   

 ConnectionInfoListener {

protected static final int CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE = 20;
private View mContentView = null;
private WifiP2pDevice device;
private WifiP2pInfo info;
ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_detail, null);
    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setOnClickListener(new      

    View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
            config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
            config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Press back   
       to cancel",
                    "Connecting to :" + device.deviceAddress, true, true
     //                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    //
    //                            @Override
   //                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface     
  dialog) {
  //                                ((DeviceActionListener)      
  getActivity()).cancelDisconnect();
  //                            }
 //                        }
                    );
            ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).connect(config);

        }
    });

    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_disconnect).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).disconnect();
                }
            });




    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                    // registered apps
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);


                }
            });

    return mContentView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // User has picked an image. Transfer it to group owner i.e peer using
    // FileTransferService.
    Uri uri = data.getData();

    TextView statusText = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
    statusText.setText("Sending: " + uri);
    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Intent----------- " + uri);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileTransferService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, uri.toString());
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS,
            info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8988);
    getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    this.info = info;
    this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // The owner IP is now known.
    TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
    view.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.group_owner_text)
            + ((info.isGroupOwner == true) ? getResources().getString(R.string.yes)
                    : getResources().getString(R.string.no)));

    // InetAddress from WifiP2pInfo struct.
    view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
    view.setText("Group Owner IP - " + info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());

    // After the group negotiation, we assign the group owner as the file
    // server. The file server is single threaded, single connection server
    // socket.
    if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
        new FileServerAsyncTask(getActivity(), mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text))
                .execute();
    } else if (info.groupFormed) {
        // The other device acts as the client. In this case, we enable the
        // get file button.
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text)).setText(getResources()
                .getString(R.string.client_text));
    }

    // hide the connect button
    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

/**
 * Updates the UI with device data
 * 
 * @param device the device to be displayed
 */
public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
    this.device = device;
    this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
    view.setText(device.deviceAddress);
    view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
    view.setText(device.toString());

}

/**
 * Clears the UI fields after a disconnect or direct mode disable operation.
 */
public void resetViews() {
    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
    view.setText(R.string.empty);
    view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
    view.setText(R.string.empty);
    view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
    view.setText(R.string.empty);
    view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
    view.setText(R.string.empty);
    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

/**
 * A simple server socket that accepts connection and writes some data on
 * the stream.
 */
public static class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    private TextView statusText;
    String response = "";

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param statusText
     */
    public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context, View statusText) {
        this.context = context;
        this.statusText = (TextView) statusText;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
            /*final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                    + context.getPackageName() + "/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".jpg");

            File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
            if (!dirs.exists())
                dirs.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();

            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
            InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
            copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));*/

            InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
                    new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
             while ((bytesRead = inputstream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");

                    serverSocket.close();
                }

           // return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return response;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {

            statusText.setText("File copied - " + response);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + result), "image/*");


        }

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        statusText.setText("Opening a server socket");
    }

}

public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);

        }
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

the part that requires change is:

```
mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                    // registered apps
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);


                }
```

Thanks For your help.

Comment: If my answer helped, please upvote/accept it so that others will benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

In your FileServerAsync class' function doInBackground, your are receiving the response and saving it in the String object you created called "response". Once the doInBackground function terminates, the AsyncTask class will call the function onPostExecute. In this function you should set the response text to a TextView. You can create a global variable for a TextView and then in this function you simply add: textView.setText(response+"");

As for removing the option to let the user chooses a picture, you should remove the content in this function:  mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(...

Cause in this function, your creating an Intent to go get an image. Instead you simply add an EditText where the user inputs a String that he wants to transmit.

Hope this helps, let me know for any updates or issues.